# Setting sender name in Java mailing service?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mailing

I'm using Mailing Service Javamail Api, I'm setting sender name like this

```
MailService mailService =   MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
MailService.Message message = new MailService.Message();
String senderName   = custInfo.getSenderName() != null ? custInfo.getSenderName() : "Sender";
senderName          =   StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(senderName);
String setSender = senderName+" "+"<" +custInfo.getCustomer().getKey()+"."+custInfo.getCompany().getKey()+"@"+appID+".appspotmail.com>";
message.setSender(setSender);
```

It's failing, the email are not going, when I'm having the sender name with comma (,) and building mail Id with that. I didn't get any exception either.
If I have like this Chandan, Photography.

Comment: Commas are not allowed in an email address.

Comment: Also, "its breaking" - not very helpful. You need to elaborate on the problem.

Comment: Yeah. I have a doubt, it is a sender Name just a string, not email address right. It's working fine with javax.mail.MailMessage.Like this same sender name
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, sendersName));         what's wrong with that?

Comment: the sender has to be an administrator.

Comment: Yeah sender is administrator.but not sure what was the problem is

Comment: If senderName has a comma, you need to enclose it in quotes.

Comment: Quotes didn't work. But I did like this message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sMailId,senderName).toString()); This is working fine. Thanks